# LeetCode 68. Text Justification

Tags: python, programming-challenge, formatting

I am trying out [Leetcode problem 68](https://leetcode.com/problems/text-justification/) and I need your help to asses the code. I am pretty new to this.

> Given an array of strings `words` and a width `maxWidth`, format the text such that each line has exactly `maxWidth` characters and is fully (left and right) justified.
>
> You should pack your words in a greedy approach; that is, pack as many words as you can in each line. Pad extra spaces `' '` when necessary so that each line has exactly `maxWidth` characters.
>
> Extra spaces between words should be distributed as evenly as possible. If the number of spaces on a line does not divide evenly between words, the empty slots on the left will be assigned more spaces than the slots on the right.
>
> For the last line of text, it should be left-justified and no extra space is inserted between words.
>
> Note:
>
> A word is defined as a character sequence consisting of non-space characters only.
> Each word's length is guaranteed to be greater than 0 and not exceed `maxWidth`.
> The input array `words` contains at least one word.

#### Example 1:

```
Input: words = ["This", "is", "an", "example", "of", "text", "justification."], maxWidth = 16
Output:
[
   "This    is    an",
   "example  of text",
   "justification.  "
]
```

#### Example 2:

```
Input: words = ["What","must","be","acknowledgment","shall","be"], maxWidth = 16
Output:
[
  "What   must   be",
  "acknowledgment  ",
  "shall be        "
]
```

> Explanation: Note that the last line is "shall be    " instead of "shall     be", because the last line must be left-justified instead of fully-justified.
> Note that the second line is also left-justified because it contains only one word.

#### Example 3:

```
Input: words = ["Science","is","what","we","understand","well","enough","to","explain","to","a","computer.","Art","is","everything","else","we","do"], maxWidth = 20
Output:
[
  "Science  is  what we",
  "understand      well",
  "enough to explain to",
  "a  computer.  Art is",
  "everything  else  we",
  "do                  "
]
```

#### Constraints:

> 1 <= words.length <= 300
> 1 <= words[i].length <= 20
> words[i] consists of only English letters and symbols.
> 1 <= maxWidth <= 100
> words[i].length <= maxWidth

I want to know if I can optimize this solution.

Full Disclaimer: My friend helped me out with this solution.

Approach : Dynamic Programming
Time Complexity : O(n)
Space Complexity : O(n)

My solution is as follows:

```
class TextJustification(object):
    def fullJustify(self, words: List[str], maxWidth: int) -> List[str]:
        
        # assign variables that you are going to use them later
        idx = 0
        ans = []
        temp = []
        temp_str = ''
        temp_len = 0
        
        # start the for-loop and end it when it reaches the last word.
        while idx < len(words):
            # take the word that we are currently looking at
            word = words[idx]
            
            """
            projected_len describes the length the line will have if the current word is            added. If temp list is empty, then there wont be any extra space. As in if there is only one word in the line, the extra spaces can be added after words. If there are more than 1 word in a line, we need to get an extra space that will come before the 2nd word so there is a space between 1st word and 2nd word.
            """
            if len(temp) == 0:
                projected_len = len(word) + temp_len
            else:
                projected_len = len(word) + temp_len + 1

            if (projected_len) <= maxWidth:
                
                """
                The same logic is here. If the len of temp is zero means that yet there is no word in a possible line so no need to add 1 to that space. If the len is non-zero, we need to add 1 space that will be added after the 1st word and before 2nd word.
                """
                if len(temp) != 0:
                    temp_len += 1

                idx += 1
                temp.append(word)
                temp_len += len(word)
            """
            If the program comes here to run, we know that there is only going to be one word in the line and hence we just add extra spaces at the end and append to the ans array.
            """
            elif len(temp) == 1:
                    temp_str = temp[0] + ' ' * (maxWidth - len(temp[0]))
                    temp.clear()
                    ans.append(temp_str)
                    temp_str = ''
                    temp_len = 0
            else:
                """
                This tells us how many partitions will be made, which will be less than the length of the array.
                """
                partitions = len(temp) - 1
                # this tells us what is the combined length of all the words that are in temp array
                total_words_len = temp_len - len(temp) + 1
                
                # this gives us the total spaces that we need to divide among the words that we have
                spaces_to_divide = maxWidth - total_words_len

                # if partitions:
                # this tell us the spaces that wont be equally divided
                remainder_spaces = spaces_to_divide % partitions
                
                # this tells us the spaces that will be equally divided
                space_with_each_partition = spaces_to_divide // partitions
                
                for temp_idx in range(len(temp)):
                    # For every partition, there will be spaces at the end of that word. This can't happen at the end of the word, hence this if condition and we decrement the partitions variable to detect that
                    if partitions:
                        temp_str += temp[temp_idx] + ' ' * space_with_each_partition
                        partitions -= 1
                    else:
                        temp_str += temp[temp_idx]
                    
                    """
                    We are told in the question that " If the number of spaces on a line do not divide evenly between words, the empty slots on the left will be assigned more spaces than the slots on the right." So we keep adding an extra space every time we get to know that there is a remainder space.
                    """
                    if remainder_spaces:
                        remainder_spaces -= 1
                        temp_str += ' '
                
                # Now we are out of the loop that adds spaces. So, we clear all the variables and append the string to the array
                temp.clear()
                ans.append(temp_str)
                temp_str = ''
                temp_len = 0

        
        "Here we do this to check if there is any word in the temp array, If so we execute the following condition."
        if temp:
            temp_str = ''
            # This is to gather all the words in the array to a string
            for temp_idx in range(len(temp)):
                temp_str += temp[temp_idx]
                temp_str += ' '
            
            # As I mentioned before that there is no need for space at the end of the word so we remove the space that we added at the end of the last word:
            temp_str = temp_str[:-1]
            
            # add the spaces that are needed at the end of the array
            new_temp_str = temp_str + ' ' * (maxWidth - len(temp_str))
            
            # append last line to the final array
            ans.append(new_temp_str)
        
        # return the ans
        return ans
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use pointless classes**. TextJustification isn't doing anything, and
`self` is never used. Just write an ordinary function.

**The comment formatting is unusual and awkward**. (1) Doc-string are intended
to document a class, function, or method. They are not intended as a fancy
device for ordinary code comments. (2) Do your reader a favor and line-wrap
those extra long comments.

**Needless verbosity can undermine the effectiveness of code comments**. It's
excellent that you are striving to write readable, well-documented code.
However, comments work best when they reinforce code clarity rather than trying
to carry the burden on their own. And if the comments become too verbose, most
readers will abandon them and simply read the code (that's what I did, for
example, when experimenting with your program). Always place most of your
emphasis on writing clear code with well-named functions and variables (more
below). Once that foundation is in place, use comments judiciously to provide
additional context and organizational cues to the reader. In many cases, such
comments can be quite brief (again, see below). Finally, one almost never needs
comments that merely state what is already obvious from the code. Here's one of
several examples of that kind of thing from your code:

```
# start the for-loop and end it when it reaches the last word.
while idx < len(words):
    # take the word that we are currently looking at
    word = words[idx]
```

**When feasible, use substantive names rather than generic or abstract names**.
Your primary status-tracking variables are `idx`, `ans`, `temp`, `temp_str`,
and `temp_len`. The first name is fine, although I would tend to shorten to
just `i`, which is a thoroughly conventional and well-understood name for a
sequence index. The other names, however, are more abstract than substantive.
What is `temp`? It's a sequence of words for the current line, so names like
`words` or `current` or even `curr` would be better. What is `temp_str`? It's a
line of text, so `line` or `text` would be better. And what is `ans`? It is a
sequence of `lines`, so call it that.

**The current program gets stuck if max width is too low**. You should either
raise an exception or shove at least one word on every line.

**A Python bool can function as an integer**. In a couple cases, your logic can
be simplified by taking advantage of the fact that `True` and `False` can also
be used numerically as `1` and `0`.

**The three-part if-else structure forces you to repeat variable resetting
code**. Most of the code resides in a three-part conditional structure: one
branch if the word fits in the current line; and two branches when it doesn't,
one for a single-word line and one for multi-word line. That logical structure
forces you to repeat the variable-resetting code in the latter two branches. In
such situations you should rearrange things either by handling the first branch
separately and then using `continue`, or by using two layers of if-else
branching. Alternatively (and this is the route I ended up pursuing below), you
can try to generalize the logic a bit, eliminating the need to worry about the
distinction between single-word and multi-word lines.

**Keep your main algorithm simpler by delegating secondary calculations to
utility functions**. Your code handles two main tasks: grouping words that will
fit into a line; and building a padded line from those words. Moving the
line-padding logic to a separate function is especially helpful in your case,
because you have three somewhat-repetitive chunks of padding code to handle a
single-word line, a multi-word line, and the non-justified final line. Moving
padding to a function eliminates most of that repetition and consolidates the
logic in one spot, which improves readability.

**Some alternative padding logic to consider**. Your primary logic for
line padding is reasonable, but it is overburdened by comments is more complex
that it needs to be. Here's how I approached the problem. Every line consists
of a sequence of pairs: each word is followed by zero or more spaces. So the
primary task is to compute the padding widths, both for the justify case and
for the final-line case. I started by knowing the the basic structure of the
function I wanted:

```
def padded_line(words, max_width, justify):
    if justify:
        widths = ...
    else:
        widths = ...
    return ''.join(
        w + (' ' * wid)
        for w, wid in zip(words, widths)
    )
```

In the `justify = True` case, we need to figure out the total number of spaces
to be added to the line and then allocate that space among the gaps between the
words. When that allocation cannot be perfectly even, we want the remainder to
be distributed among the initial words in the line. And the final width is
necessarily zero, because we are fully justifying the line. In the `justify = False` case, the widths between the words are all one, and the rest of the
space is given to the last width. Here's what I ended up with. Among other
things, note the commenting strategy: most of the clarity comes from variable
naming and algorithmic simplicity; the comments are brief and mostly play an
organizational role in this case. Finally, note the use of a `bool` in an
arithmetic context to distribute the remainder.

```
def padded_line(words, max_width, justify):
    # N of spaces to be distributed among the gaps.
    n_spaces = max_width - sum(len(w) for w in words)
    n_gaps = len(words) - 1

    # Compute padding widths.
    if justify:
        wid, remainder = divmod(n_spaces, n_gaps)
        widths = [wid + int(i < remainder) for i in range(n_gaps)]
        widths.append(0)
    else:
        widths = [1 for _ in range(n_gaps)]
        widths.append(n_spaces - n_gaps)

    # Return padded line.
    return ''.join(
        w + (' ' * wid)
        for w, wid in zip(words, widths)
    )
```

**Justifying the text: code clarity enhanced by judicious commenting**. With
that utility function in place and with the other suggestions discussed above,
we end up with the following code to justify the text. Again, note the
comments: even though they are quite brief, they help with readability by
giving context (eg, explaining how we are using the 3 primary variables), by
providing reasoning and narrative (eg, the comments in the three if-else
branches), or merely by providing simple organizational cues (eg, "Process the
words" and the last comment, neither of which is very substantive, maintain
organizational symmetry across the code by ensuring that every code
sub-section starts with a comment). Even though the comments do aid readability
in notable ways, most of the clarity comes from the code itself: substantive
naming, intuitive algorithmic strategy and structure, and delegating
computational details to other functions.

```
def full_justify(words, max_width):
    # All lines, the words for current line, and their combined width.
    lines = []
    curr = []
    width = 0

    # Process the words.
    N = len(words)
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        word = words[i]
        new_width = width + len(word) + bool(curr)
        if new_width <= max_width:
            # The word fits: add it to current line.
            i += 1
            curr.append(word)
            width = new_width
        elif curr:
            # The word does not fit: build the current line and reset.
            lines.append(padded_line(curr, max_width, justify = True))
            curr = []
            width = 0
        else:
            # The word does not fit, even by itself.
            raise ValueError('max_width cannot be less than the smallest word width')

    # Handle words for last line and return.
    if curr:
        lines.append(padded_line(curr, max_width, justify = False))
    return lines
```